# Cisco ACE HTTP Logging

Tags: apache, http, logging, cisco

I have a pretty naive question.  I know the Cisco ACE has the ability to log events via syslog, but does it have the ability to log details about the HTTP traffic that it processes?  For example, I would love to see something similar to an Apache commons access log with client IP, time, request URI, response code, and most importantly load balancing information, like which back-end server the request was forwarded to.

I would like to send all of this over syslog.  Is anyone familiar with doing this?  Thanks in advance.